# Use Angular routing in an Apache-hosted app

Tags: angularjs, apache, configuration

My app's frontend is done in Angular while the backend is in PHP. For this last reason, I am using Apache as app server.

I want to use Angular's routing feature, that is, `$routeProvider.when()`, with conditional params (aka named groups) such as `/user/:id/`, where `:id` would be a parameter passed to the controller specified in the route.

Obviously, Apache tries to handle the request e.g., `/user/21` by looking for a resource called `21` inside of the `user` directory, and thus returns a 404 error, instead of letting Angular routing load the resource at `/user` and using the value `21` to do internal stuff (such as calling an API).

How would I have to **setup Apache** so that some **requests are left to be handled by Angular**?

Comment: Don't you want your requests to be handled with php, not Angular? Surely you only want to use Angular to _build_ the request?

Comment: In my app, PHP is merely used for some templating issues and global variables. So yes, I still want Angular to handle routing.

Comment: I take you are using html5Mode(true)

Comment: Yes, I am using `html5Mode(true)`.